# Redirect and remove folder in url .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, dns

I am trying to redirect from **http://example.org/family/** to **http://example.org/family/public** without showing in the url the folder public, so I want to keep the url the same after redirecting.

I've been reading a lot of different solutions but I haven't got the result I want. Currently I have a .htaccess in the 'family' folder but it redirects to the public folder and shows a 404 error:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /family
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It should show the content in the index.php but it doesn't. The .htaccess inside the public folder is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/public/(.*) /$1 [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: (out of topic) may i know is it an Laravel application ?

Comment: yes, it is a Laravel app

Comment: why you want to control this with htaccess ? don't you do that with your domain file path ? its an security purpose that laravel uses public folder to serve first

Comment: Because my laravel app it's inside a folder so the url of my application is: domain.com/family/public. The problem I have right now is that once i'm inside the public folder, it doesn't find the index.php

Comment: actually i am not giving this question solution but trying to get the bypass solution for that. please set your domain path as  domain.com/family/public and reset all default ht-access files. don't need change anything. i deployed laravel app on many server, but none of them cause any problem in that way

Comment: Okay! I'm gonna try. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've tried and now I think I've got all the configuration files as the original ones. But now I get a 404 error. So where do I have to set my domain path?

Comment: may i know which server you using ?

Comment: easy way you can make an subdomain and set the path for that subdomain. it will be very easy for you

Comment: Finally I've got the result I want combining two answers: i've fixed my laravel config files and i've created a new subdomain which points to laravel/public. Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0):

This would be your solution, it will redirect all request to the subfolder public

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /family
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/family/public
RewriteRule (.*) family/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! With your answer my website redirects without changing the url, but now it doesn't find the index.php by default. Now I'll edit my post with these new changes. I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the best solution, but you can try ProxyPass:

if you are using Apache, edit `httpd.conf` add this line

`ProxyPass /family http://example.org/family2/public`
Also, make sure the following lines are uncommented, so you get the right proxy and submodule to reroute http requests:

`LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so`

Then restart the server, all what is inside the dir `family2/public` it has to show to `family`

Comment: I am working in a shared hosting so I can't change those parameters. But thank you!